# how to pass a constant value to nested column with mybaits association

Tags: associations, mybatis

how can I pass constant value '1111' to a nested column with mybatis association?

```
<association property="certificateType" column="{VALUE=CERTIFICATE_TYPE,TYPE='1111'}" select="getDict"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your db is, you can use

`IFNULL(#{TYPE}, '1111')` (mysql)

`ISNULL(#{TYPE}, '1111')` (sql server)

In your subquery (getDict).

Another solution is that your parent query can return TYPE as a value

For example by saying:

`SELECT '1111' AS TYPE, .....`

Then in your column you can just say

`column={VALUE=CERTIFICATE_TYPE,TYPE=TYPE}`

Hope that helps.

Comment: The second solution works. Interface of "getDict" will handle different types, that's why I consider to pass variable i.o. hardcode in subquery. Anyway, thanks.