# MyBatis accessing method parameter in subquery

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I currently have this result map:

```
 <resultMap id="one" type="FirstType" autoMapping="true">
        <collection property="listProp" column="example_id" 
           ofType="SecondType" select="subQuery">
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

Dao:

```java
    List<FirstType> one(@Param("params") ParamObject obj);
```

I can access the param object in my parent query and it's all good but I can't access it in my sub query. Is it possible to pass the obj param to subquery?

Comment: The `subQuery` receives the value of `column`. Please see the explanation about "nested select" in the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html).

Comment: @ave I know that. I don't think you understood what I'm trying to do. I want to pass obj to the nested query.

Comment: I am pretty sure I do. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324271/1261766).

Comment: it does not let me simply pass the object. If I want to pass it I would need to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324271/19957114) for every field in the pojo

Comment: Yes, that is correct.